# Android Error "AbstractMethodError: abstract method androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper.getDataBinder

Tags: java, android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a library made by me, the library uses databinding, I export the library as an aar file. I have a test project where the library works for me, but when I import it into another project, it gives me the following error:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method
> "androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding
> androidx.databinding.DataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent,
> android.view.View, int)"
> at
> androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:79)
> at
> androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:199)
> at
> androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bindToAddedViews(DataBindingUtil.java:327)
> at
> androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:306)
> at
> androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
> at
> org.sigmaaie.mobile.survey.ui.SurveyActivity.setupBinding(SurveyActivity.kt:27)
> at
> com.sigma.core.ui.BaseModuleActivity.onCreate(BaseModuleActivity.kt:54)
> at
> org.sigmaaie.mobile.survey.ui.SurveyActivity.onCreate(SurveyActivity.kt:22)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8109)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8083)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3452)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3651)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2104)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)

In both projects, databinding is enabled.

I tried to remove all pro-guards rules

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. Aar library failing after R8 with databinding.

Please try adding to library project proguard-rules:

> -keep class androidx.databinding.** { *; }

This seems to have fixed issue for me.

Comment: i have multiple modules do i need to add this to all modules for it to wrok